NFS mount fails with peculiar errors (as plain user and root)
When I try to manually mount with this command:
     mount -t nfs <server-ip>:/srv/nfs4/share1 /mnt/data

as non-root user,
I am getting the error mount.nfs: failed to apply fstab options. 
When I try the same command with sudo:
sudo mount -t nfs <server-ip>:/srv/nfs4/share1 /mnt/data

..., I get the error mount.nfs: Operation not permitted.
I have tried modifying access options, such as using no_hide. 
I have also tried
sudo chown nobody:nobody /srv/nfs4/share1

but the error won't go away, so the clients still have no access.

I have verified that the NFS server is up and running from systemd.
I have checked the exports with showmount -e <server-ip-addr>.

I am running the NFS Server on Arch Linux,
and the clients are Fedora-based... 
What am I missing here that resolves this problem?

I discovered that running commands such as mount is not allowed on unpriviledge containers while researching this problem. There could be a walkaround that uses mount --bind while on nfs4 that could make this work but I am yet to fully decode how it should be properly done after trying:
mount --bind /mnt/nfs4share /srv/nfs4/exports
Then re-exporting and restarting the nfs-server
